# How to force href to use non secure hyperlinks?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

Using the Wordpress framework i have one problem when trying to add a non secure link in one of my posts. for example adding the

```
<a href="http://www.somepage.com">SomePage</a>
```

will open always the secure page =>

```
https://www.somepage.com
```

Any ideas how to force using non secure protocol?

Comment: If the site you're linking to has redirects in place to force SSL then no, there's nothing in your control you can do.

Comment: so you mean if the site which is in my example the www.somepage.com has redirects in place to force ssl it wont work? or do you mean the site where the link is represented? Best thanks though!

Comment: If somepage.com has rules in place to redirect to HTTPS then you can't do anything about it, even if you link to HTTP in your `a`.